# How I can get user ID when I use {.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)}

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose

I want to get the UID after I create a user `fun createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and initialize it to `usrID` in my `user` object type of `UserProfile`  after that I call `fun addUser`

```
fun createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String,user: UserProfile) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        auth
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .await()

    }
    //user.userID = userID
    //addUser(user)
}

fun addUser(user: UserProfile) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        UserRepository.addUser(user)
    }
}
```

```
private val usersDocumentRef by lazy {
    UserRepository.db.collection("usersProfiles")
}

suspend fun addUser(user: UserProfile) {
    usersDocumentRef.document(user.userID).set(user).await()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Firebase user with the given email address and password is successfully created, then it means that it is also signed in. That being said, you can get the UID of the user right from the [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) object like this:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()
user.userID = auth.currentUser?.uid
addUser(user)
```

Comment: Hey there. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Its works, I marked  

Answer (score 0):

```
// add the import 
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

// you can rename the function what ever you want 
 const onRegister = () => {
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      Alert.alert("Password don't match.");
      return;
    }
    if (email && password) {
      auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(userCredential => {
           // the user inframtion in firebase are saved under name name of userCredential 
          console.log(userCredential);
          // after seeing the data on the console log you can call it by userCredential.user.add the name of the argument also known as parameter

          const user = userCredential.user;
          const userId = user.uid;
          
          console.log(userId);
          //seting the loaction and name of the doc
          firestore().collection('Users').doc(userId).set({
            userId,
          });
          console.log('firestore uploaded');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
            console.log('That email address is already in use!');
          }
          if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
            console.log('That email address is invalid!');
          }
          console.error(error);
        });
    } else {
      Alert.alert('Please fill in details!');
    }
  };
```